# Associative array not storing first result from SQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have a database in MySQL and I'm using this query to select certain rows from it using PHP:

```
$q = "SELECT Number, Body 
      FROM boxes 
      WHERE Number BETWEEN '1' AND '4' ORDER BY Number ASC";
```

Then calling the query and initiating arrays:

```
$r = $mysqli->query($q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$array = array();
$content = array();
```

Then attempting to sort the results into an associative array where the 'number' is the key and the 'body' is the value.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    $array = array(
    $content[$row['Number']] = $row['Body']
);
```

This works fine except it will not store the first value. This is the result of print_r($content);, missing the first row.

```
Array ( [2] => This is entry two [3] => This is entry three [4] => This is entry four )
```

I have tried running the SQL query within PHPMyAdmin and it returns all four rows as I would expect.

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`
You are getting first returned row by this line. You have to remove it and it will work properly.

`mysqli_fetch_array` and `mysqli_fetch_assoc` returning NEXT row on every call.

Comment: Looks like that got it. Seems incredibly obvious now! Thank you